# Chess Position Trainer in Conjunction with Chessbase or Similar

Tags: opening, software, training

I have a repertoire stored in Chessbase and currently export these as PGNs when updated, and train them in ChessTempo for its spaced repetition. I do not like the Chessbase repertoire training feature, as it doesn't let me go through my entire repertoire.

Enter Chess Position Trainer. I am battling through the manual during the evaluation period. My questions are:

a) can you train your entire repertoire in one swoop? Or are you forced to choose each opening module and train one at a time? I am thinking along the lines of ChessTempo's white/black repertoire with spaced repetition.

b) does anyone have a decent workflow for exporting Chessbase repertoires and importing them into CPT? If I make small adjustments in Chessbase, how much destruction will I cause to my current CPT repertoire my importing that new PGN? I understand that it will add new positions, but will it delete old unused ones?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Owen. To be honest, your question has A LOT of "moving parts", and I know that I cannot answer it in its current form since it would require knowing three pieces of software, and the odds of someone knowing all three well are slim. I would suggest that you take some screenshots, and instead of telling us how you want to solve the problem, show us what you want to accomplish, and let us see if we can present you with a solution as to how to help you study the way you want. I face this all the time in IT: A user just yesterday asked me a long question back-and-forth question about...

Comment: using system restore. All the user was trying to really do was restore a deleted desktop shortcut. I walked him through that MUCH easier process instead. You can do what you wish, but that is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> a) can you train your entire repertoire in one swoop? Or are you
>   forced to choose each opening module and train one at a time?

you have to choose the opening you want to train.  However, you have control of what is included in an "opening"  The only constraint is that White and Black must be separate.  So you could have a single "white" opening and a single "black" opening to train.

I have two white openings and three black openings.